# Getting "error: ":" expected at the end of the line" when it is clearly present. (GDScript)

Tags: godot, gdscript

I have tried restarting the engine and rewriting the code but i still get an error asking for a colon on the end of the line.

```
while angle not in range(-360, 360):
```

Relevant code if it helps:

```
func _physics_process(delta):
    angle = self.rotation_degrees
    while angle not in range(-360, 360):
        if angle > 360:
            angle -= 360
        elif angle < -360:
            angle += 360
```

Edit: Fixed indentation in the code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `not in` is not valid GDScript syntax.

I believe this is what you want:

```
while not angle in range(-360, 360):
```

---

With that said, you seem to be going on a convoluted way to wrap the angle. You can do this for the same effect:

```
angle = wrapf(angle, -360, 360)
```

*Using `wrapf` is very useful to normalize angle. For example, `wrapf(angle, -180, 180)` or `wrapf(angle, 0, 360)` for degrees or `wrapf(angle, -PI, PI)` or `wrapf(angle, 0, TAU)` for radians.*

---

What does `wrapf` do? It wraps a float value around an interval. If the value is gone past one end of the interval, pretend it entered by the opposite end. For example `wrapf(14, 0, 10)` is `4`, and `wrapf(-4, 0, 10)` is `6`.

If I wanted to make a wrap function replacement in GDScript it would look like this:

```
func wrap(value:float, from:float, to:float) -> float:
    var diff := to - from
    return value - (diff * floor((value - from) / diff))
```

*You don't have to. This is just for reference.*